# Low Breakover Voltage Diac

Tags: voltage, dc, thyristor

I wanted to know if there is commercially available Diacs with Breakover Voltage of 20V or less. I tried to find in the internet but always ending up to Diacs with Breakover Voltage of around 30V or more.

I just want to build some circuit that has feature of activating it when it overcomes some "threshold" voltage. That is why I want to use the breakover voltage characteristic of Diac. The circuit should be done using my 24 V DC supply.

If there is no such thing, please provide me an alternative to it.

Comment: I used to see diacs available in two specific voltages: 30 - 32V and 8V.  I have no idea if the 8V diacs are still available.

Comment: Actually, pounding the string " diac 8V " into Google shows that they are readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Most diacs have a breakdown in the 30V range. You could use [SIDAC](http://www.pwrx.com/pwrx/docs/bs08d.pdf), which has a breakdown in the 7~9V range.

If you don't need the bidirectional characteristic, a programmable UJT such as the 2N6028 could be used.

But for most circuits requiring a threshold, comparators, op-amps used as comparators, discrete transistors and zener diodes, or even microcontrollers with ADCs are probably better modern-day solutions.